# cannot add foreign key constraint when linking two tables with each other

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE product (
id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(50), 
weight FLOAT, 
fat FLOAT, 
protein FLOAT, 
carbohydrates FLOAT, 
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

the error occurs when i create a new table with a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE saleline (
id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_id INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES 
product(id));
```

This is the error message:

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

what should i do to fix this?

Comment: Show us the error message.

Comment: @jarlh this is the error message `ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Comment: Does changing `product_id INTEGER` to `product_id INTEGER UNSIGNED` help?

Comment: 'The size and sign of integer types must be the same.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Add **UNSIGNED**  after **product_id INTEGER**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should have the same type `INTEGER UNSIGNED` when you add foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE saleline (
id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
product_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES 
product(id));
```